# fixed bottom navbar - how to get the links spread out over full size and responsible (with %?) navbar-justified wont work

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, alignment, navbar

:)
I m fiddeling around with my bootstrap fixed bottom navbar..
its working kinda ..
But my navbar links wont go justified .. i tried everything i could think about.. 
i want to have it responsive soo the code i m currantly having (60px padding) is just the best i came up with, - looks soo aweful if it resizes.. :( 
thx a lot!!!

```
    <!--NAVBAR-->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-bottom" role="navigation">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
          <li class="active"><a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img src="Bilder/grafik4.jpg" type="picture/jpg"/></a></li>
        </div>

        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">

            <li><a href="#">F</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Z</a></li> 
            <li><a href="#">V</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Ns</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Englisch</a></li>
            <li class="dropdown">
              <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Kontakt und Impressum<b class="caret"></b></a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a href="#">A</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Kontakt</a></li>
                <li class="divider"></li>
                <li><a href="#">Webseitengestaltung</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Foto und Film</a></li>
                <li class="divider"></li>
                <li><a href="#">Copyright 2014</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
      </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
    </nav>
    <!--NAVBAR ENDE-->
```

the custom css is (other than that i used the bootstrap 3 one):

```
` 
.navbar-brand {
float: left;
font-size: 18px;
height: 50px;
line-height: 20px;
padding-left: 40px;
padding-top:5px;
text-decoration: none;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:hover,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:focus {

background-color: transparent;
color:black;
text-decoration:underline;
}


.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a {
color: grey;
text-decoration: none;
width: 100%;
padding-left:60px;
}


.navbar-nav > li > a {
padding-top: 15px;
padding-bottom: 15px;
size: 60px;
margin: 14,82% 0 0 10%;
}

.navbar-default {

background-color: #FFFFFF;
border-color: #E7E7E7;
}

.dropdown-menu > li > a {
color: grey;

}
.dropdown-menu> li > a:hover,
.dropdown-menu> li > a:focus {
background-color: transparent;
color:black;
text-decoration:underline;
}
`
```

Comment: Please include your CSS as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this solution (if I understand correct what you want). **[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Nicolai8/N75zT/3/)**:

I just replaced `<ul class="nav navbar-nav">` with `<ul class="nav custom-menu nav-justified">`.

The `nav-justified` is provided by bootstrap.

Also I made few modifications to your css.

**HTML:**

```
<!--NAVBAR-->
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-bottom" role="navigation">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <li class="active"><a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
                <img src="http://placehold.it/20x20" type="picture/jpg" /></a>
            </li>
        </div>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
            <ul class="nav custom-menu nav-justified">
                <li><a href="#">F</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Z</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">V</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Ns</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Englisch</a>
                </li>
                <li class="dropdown"><a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Kontakt und Impressum <b class="caret"></b></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li><a href="#">A</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Kontakt</a></li>
                        <li class="divider"></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Webseitengestaltung</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Foto und Film</a></li>
                        <li class="divider"></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Copyright 2014</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>
<!--NAVBAR ENDE-->
```

**CSS:**

```
.navbar-default .custom-menu > li a {
    color: grey;
}
.dropdown-menu > li > a:hover {
    color: white;
}
.custom-menu > li > a {
    padding-top: 15px;
    padding-bottom: 15px;
}
.navbar-default {
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    border-color: #E7E7E7;
}
.custom-menu > li > a:hover {
    background-color: transparent;
    color:black;
    text-decoration:underline;
}
.navbar-default .dropdown.open {
    background-color: #eee;
    color:black;
    text-decoration:underline;
}
.nav>li>a{
    padding:15px 0;
}
```

---

**EDIT:**
**[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Nicolai8/N75zT/5/)**

To make dropdown menu as before add few things:

1. Add `id="menu"` for `ul` element:
2. Add new css class. It's need to align to center menu items when they are collapsed:

   .navbar-nav{
       margin:inherit !important;
   }
3. Add javascript that will replace `custom-menu` class to `navbar-nav` class when toggle button is visible; otherwise it will do opposite thing.

   `$(function () {
       $(window).resize(function () {
           changeMenu();
       });
       changeMenu();

       function changeMenu() {
           if ($(".navbar-toggle").is(":visible")) {
               $("#menu").removeClass("custom-menu").addClass("navbar-nav");
           } else {
               $("#menu").removeClass("navbar-nav").addClass("custom-menu");
           }
       }
   });`

Comment: that s exactely i wanted. - sorry i should have sayed it more clearely.. 
the problem i have now, is that if i rezize my page and the menue gets to a collpsable menue, the dropdown is just a little box on top instead it folds down inside the menue... -thx a lot anyway

Comment: @Ulya, please check Edit section of my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you are after, but [here is a codepen](http://codepen.io/lukeocom/pen/Axmcj) with a fixed menu at the bottom of the page. It's elements are centered using `text-align:center` for the `ul`. The navbar is 'responsive' as it resizes with the window. However for a proper responsive design you should use [@media queries](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/) to set specific rules for different devices.

hope this helps.

Comment: hey.. :) 
Thx for your help.. i did not clerefy enough what i want... so it s not the solution... but thx a lot anyway.. i tried text align center and it just has my links centered and not spread out over whole width.. the first comment was a great solution, exept of it s macking up my collapsable menue.. :(

Comment: Ah ok, no worries. In that case, I think you need to set the margin of the <li> tags and not the <a> tags. Something like margin:0 5% 0 0; will set the right margin of each so they're spaced out. Then use media queries for small devices. Here's an update http://codepen.io/lukeocom/pen/oqKwj